# No Activity found to handle Intent - WebView

Tags: javascript, android, ios, android-intent, webview

Team,

I have a WebView and I need to invoke native application based on some context from javascript layer. I tried to perform Window.location="xxxx://service" in javascript, so I thought to handle the intent call in native application and perform some actions based on the context. I am getting the below exception, please let me know how to resolve..

Also please let me know, if there is any other better way to communicate from javascript to native code (that should work for both iOS and Android).

Note: Window.location works for iOS, so thought of reusing the code (in javascript layer) and customize the native code.

Thanks,
Ramesh

08-27 09:11:08.845 32525-32525/com.example.sample1 W/ WebViewClient: No activity found to handle this type of content
                                                                         android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=xxxxx://self_serv_type$Account }
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1878)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1545)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4230)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4567)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4535)
                                                                             at com.xxx.mobile.webview.internal.HybridWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(HybridWebViewClient.java:134)
                                                                             at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:342)
                                                                             at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient.shouldIgnoreNavigation(AwContentsClient.java:168)
                                                                             at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientBridge.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(AwContentsClientBridge.java:256)
                                                                             at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
                                                                             at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                             at com.android.intern

Comment: "please let me know how to resolve" -- install or implement an Android app that has an activity that supports `ACTION_VIEW` for a URL of the form `xxxxx://self_serv_type$Account`. "if there is any other better way to communicate from javascript to native code" -- [`addJavascriptInterface()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) is "better" for some values of "better".

Comment: Thanks for your response. Am I suppose to add ACTION_VIEW in Manifest Intent Filter for that activity Or startActivity?

Comment: You are not calling `startActivity()` yourself. Some activity on the device needs to have an `ACTION_VIEW` `<intent-filter>`, where the `<data>` on the `<intent-filter>` supports a URL construct like `xxxxx://self_serv_type$Account`.